# Pandas_ta - NoneType object has no attribute copy

Tags: python, pandas

I use pandas_ta to calculate indicators such as RSI, MACD, EMA CROSS.
Unfortunately, there seems to be a problem with the closing price data.

I was passing ndarray and it didn't work so I changed it to a simple list and the result was the same.

Moreover, these arguments work with TaLib, but give more or less accurate results.

Error:
AttributeError: Object "NoneType" has no "copy" attribute

```
RSI_PERIOD = 14
MACD_FAST = 12
MACD_SLOW = 26
MACD_SIGNAL = 9
EMA_TIMEPERIOD = 10
EMA_TIMEPERIOD2 = 30

client = Client(keys.api_key, keys.secret_key)

def find_interesting_trading_tokens():
    for coin in tokens.coins:
        real_data = client.get_historical_klines(coin, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE,"1 hour ago UTC")
        m = len(real_data)
        for i in range(m):
            if i == 0:
                real_data_close_price = np.array(float(real_data[i][4]))
            else:
                real_data_close_price = np.append(real_data_close_price, float(real_data[i][4]))

        data = [123.2, 42343.2, 4343.34, 45454.43, 433545.3]
        real_data_close_price_formatted = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(real_data_close_price), columns=['close'])
        macd_pandas = pd_ta.macd(data, fast=MACD_FAST, slow=MACD_SLOW, signal=MACD_SIGNAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to provide pd.Series() not a list or ndarray. Problem solved.
In my opinion the error should inform about it